# When helicopters are instructed to air-taxi direct to an airport location, are they allowed to pass above other aircraft and people?

Tags: air-traffic-control, helicopter

When helicopters are instructed to air-taxi direct to a location at the airport, are they allowed to pass above other aircraft / people / road traffic?

Comment: The [FAA helicopter flying handbook](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/helicopter_flying_handbook/media/hfh_ch09.pdf) says "it is expected that the helicopter will remain below 100 feet AGL with an appropriate airspeed and will avoid over flight of other aircraft, vehicles, and personnel," which would make it inadvisable to do so, whether or not it's allowed.

Comment: In my experience, the helicopters stick to the taxiways and their ground clearance is similar to that of other fixed wing aircraft. They are only cleared if the taxiway is clear and allows them to reposition without conflict.

Comment: @Zach - that looks like it should be an answer (for the FAA's realm, anyway) rather than a comment.

Answer (score 2):

No. A helicopter taxiing has to follow the exact same rules as any other taxiing aircraft.