# How are rotorcraft and/or VTOL aircraft handled once they get to an airport?

Tags: air-traffic-control, rotorcraft, vtol

I am asking this from an ATC perspective ... my experience as a pilot is that they would make helicopters fly the same approach but once they got the airport environment in site where do they go? Taxi over the taxiway at XX feet?  Are they given "hold short" instructions? The whole thing is a big mystery to me.

Do they stay with tower or do they go to ground frequency even though they are still airborne?

And then for VTOL operations I guess those aircraft like the F-35B have wheels so they could land and taxi like a normal aircraft ... is that the procedure?

Comment: You usually hear the phrase "air-taxi" or "hover" a lot on Coms with helicopters. They "taxi" by flying close to the ground, but are bound to the same regulations an aircraft has when taxiing. In some cases, I guess when traffic allows, I've seen / heard helicopters taking off and landing directly from where they parked (/will park), which eliminates the need to "taxi"

Comment: Also see: [When helicopters are instructed to air-taxi direct to an airport location, are they allowed to pass above other aircraft and people?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/53073/14897)